# Rails: validate form fields step by step

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to validate different input values.
For example "domain" and "email". Both have to have a value and must be unique. So i try to validate them with

```
validates :domain,
          :presence => true,
          :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => true }
validates :email,
          :presence => true,
          :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => true }
```

But when i display the flash messages, i get four errors:

```
["Domain can't be blank", "Domain has already been taken", "Email can't be blank", "Email has already been taken"]
```

Is it possible to check them gradually? If the input field has no value, the user gets

```
["Domain can't be blank"]
```

but if the input field has a value and isn't unique, the user gets

```
["Domain has already been taken"]
```

How can i implement it?

**Edit**

Heres the code that prints the error messages:

```
<% [:error].each do |key| %>
  <% if flash[key] %>
    <div class="<%= key %>" id="flash">
      <%= flash[key] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here the controller that creates the errors:

```
def create

  respond_to do |format|
    # save form data
    @login = Login.new(params[:login])

    # if validation fails, throw error messages
    if !@login.save
      flash[:error] = @login.errors.to_a
    end

    # redirect to landingpage
   format.html { redirect_to :root }

  end

end
```

Comment: Do you already have a domain with a blank value in the database? Maybe it sees that it's already there and compares what you enter, so that gives you both errors.

Comment: No, there are no entries in the table.

Comment: Could you post your flash code, because uniqueness and presence are two different things and they shouldn't both occur for no reason. I can understand the "blank" error, but not the "non-unique" error..

Comment: You should update your question, also the code where you set the `:error` with the values would help also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash[:error]` will display all errors if you don't first call `@user.valid?` or `@user.invalid?` which will then return the errors that pertain to that `@person` object.

See the Rails guides on how to use the [Flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).
Also the [validation errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors) section.

Give this a try:

```
if !@login.save       
  flash[:error] = @login.errors.to_a if @login.invalid?
end
```

Comment: The guide also says that usually the validation should happen by default if using `[Model].create` but will not work with `[Model].new`, but since you overwrote your error handling in your implementation of `create` you have to do it manually. See [Section 2.4 - valid? and invalid?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid) for more info on that.